# Word like »Schadenfreude« that also conveys a hint of empathy

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, synonym

I'm trying to find a German word that is the same as »Schadenfreude« but also has a tinge of empathy in it. Is there such a word?

Comment: I would suggest »Häme«. See also this list: http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/schadenfreude.php

Comment: @Devon I'd say_Häme_ comes without 'a tingle of empathy'.

Comment: The point of "Schadenfreude" (gloating) is that you're taking pleasure in someone's harm. Thus there *is* already some empathy involved, just no *sympathy*.

Comment: Could you add some context, e.g. a real-life situation where you would need such a word? This would help finding one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **Belustigung**? It's a more general term, neither restricted to harm nor to malice.

Comment: That's twice as bad.

Comment: @Janka: _Schadenfreude_ has always a malicious connotation, _Belustigung_ not necessarily.

Comment: Ich empfinde "Belustigung" immer etwas hinterfotzig. Aber ok.

Answer (score 2):

There is the so called **Schmunzelfehler** which is an euphemism for a shortcoming in some good which doesn't really matter. For example a scratch on the backside of a cabinet.

It comes from *schmunzeln*, which means "to smile over something bad", and *Fehler* (error, mistake, failure).

> Ihr Gesang war kaum auszuhalten.
>
> — Oh, im Vergleich zur Band war das doch nur ein Schmunzelfehler.

*I couldn't stand her singing.*

— *Oh? Compared to the band it was merely a Schmunzelfehler.*

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard 'Schmunzelfehler' before. Is this word specific   for a certain area  or subculture or similar?

Comment: I think it's specific for people who buy/sell second-hand (or second-choice) goods.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a word that describes reacting to someone's misfortune in a humorous way, without the implied negativity.

I would suggest **Stichelei**. It is the German word for a taunt. (Note that this word can not be used for non-verbal reactions, a laughter for instance. But then again, the same is true for the English word.)